# gnucash reports seem to ignore a single currency entirely, other currencies not: how to include the currency?

Tags: finance, gnucash

In my gnucash data I operate with several currencies, incl EUR, DKK and SGD.

Now, interestingly, in all my reports, the data from the DKK accounts are included and (as intended) converted into EUR.

However, SGD accounts are seemingly ignored. 
If I change the reporting currency, EUR&DKK are ignored, but SGD included.

The only interesting warning I see is

```
gnc:get-commodity-totalavg-prices:  Sorry, currency exchange not yet implemented
```

How to proceed towards getting a report that integrates all three currencies?

Comment: I am using EUR as base currency. The problem seems to be transfers between 2 other currencies/securities only: EUR - USD works, EUR - BND works, but USD - BND causes the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem that the currency exchange mechanism for reports relies heavily on the price database.

I think by changing the report price source to '[nearest in time](https://www.gnucash.org/docs/v2.6/C/gnucash-guide/invest-stockprice1.html)' it will solve the issue.